# Different way to identify html code tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document, getelementbyid

I am trying to figure out another way to identify the html code and click.
For example,

```
<div itemprop="size" class="shoesizes sizeBox" data-isapparel="false" id="size_sku2227293" skuid="sku2194684">10.0</div>
```

I am currently using

```
var test = document.getElementById("size_sku2227293");
test.click();
```

Is there a way to get the element by the "10.0" that is in the html code instead of size_sku2227293?

Comment: You want to retrieve the text inside the node instead?

Comment: @SethenMaleno Yes I guess retrieve the text and then click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` method:

```
$('div.shoesizes').filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML === '10.0';
}).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the restrictions in the contains selector(wild char match) a better solution will be to add the size value as an attribute and then use attribute equals selector

```
<div itemprop="size" class="shoesizes sizeBox" data-size="10.0" data-isapparel="false" id="size_sku2227293" skuid="sku2194684">10.0</div>
```

then

```
$('.shoesizes[data-size="10.0"]').trigger('click')
```

Comment: So there is no need to use the keyword "document" in this case

Comment: He's just using jQuery to select the element instead.

Comment: Plus there is a caveat of wildcard match as well using contains... ex it will fetch 110.05 as well. i think filter would be a very good option.

Comment: in that case it could be advised that to add a `data-*` property indicating the size and use it along with a attribute selector

Comment: Yeah that makes it better, +1. If op is ready to use a data attr the fetch would probably be lighter than looking for the content.

Comment: @PSL then probably I should remove the first answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny probably not. Now when i think about it. Because it is shoe size you might not have too many combinations that can cause an issue, i mean not sure though.. :)